# FAKE build a project with unsafe flag

Tags: f#-fake, f#-fake-4

I am trying to build a solution where one of the projects needs to be build with the unsafe flag on, it is set correctly in the project however when building I get the error:

> "Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe"

This is my target at the moment

```ml
    Target "CompileApp" (fun _ ->
        !! @"**\*.csproj"
          |> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
          |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
    )
```

I tried adding [MsBuildParams](https://web.archive.org/web/20161113154821/https://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-msbuildhelper.html) but not sure how to use them yet (ie there doesnt seem to be an option in MsBuildRelease to add something like this

```
let setParams defaults =
    { defaults with
        Verbosity = Some(Quiet)
        Targets = ["Build"]
        Properties =
            [
                "AllowUnsafeBlocks", "True"
                "Configuration", "Release"
            ]
    }
```

Also would the best option here be create two different targets for projects with safe and unsafe code, of would there be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think this might be the way:

```
Target "CompileUnsafe" (fun _ ->          
    let buildMode = getBuildParamOrDefault "buildMode" "Release"
    let setParams defaults =
        { defaults with
            Verbosity = Some(Quiet)
            Targets = ["Build"]
            Properties =
                [
                    "Optimize", "True"
                    "DebugSymbols", "True"
                    "Configuration", buildMode
                    "AllowUnsafeBlocks", "True"
                ]
        }
    build setParams "./ProjectPlugins.sln"      
)
```

IF there are better solutions I'm all ears (the solution was there in the docs and I just missed it)

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `AllowUnsafeBlocks=true` element was only defined under the `DEBUG|AnyCPU` and `Release|AnyCPU` PropertyGroups in my project file.

Using this fixed it for me:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
    !! ".\**\MyApp.*.csproj"
    |> MSBuild buildDir "Build" ["Configuration", "Release"; "Platform", "AnyCPU"]
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I ll try this :D